# Use Excel 2010 to read/write to a SQL Server 2008 database using stored procedures

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, vba, sharepoint, stored-procedures

We have a SQL Server 2008 database that has stored procedures to handle reads/writes/etc.  These procedures are used by a variety of applications internally.

The need has come up for a single person to make updates directly to a one of the tables in the database called Employee.  The update is dirt simple; update VARCHAR and INT (foreign key) fields.  The problem is that SharePoint 2010 doesn't easily support this kind of update through BCS; browsing and updating isn't the best user experience.

It's been suggested that this is easily solved with Excel and VBA.  On open, Excel connects to the SQL Server database and reads from the Employee read stored procedure.  It also executes the read sprocs for the tables the foreign keys reference.  The user makes an update to a field, which in turn calls the Employee update sproc.

The advantages to this are that there is no website interface that needs to be built/hosted/etc; the DBA is fine with this approach if Active Directory is used to authenticate.

The problem is that I can't find a VBA programmer or any helpful resources or step-by-step walk throughs to write the VBA.

Does anyone know of such an online resource and/or have an alternate suggestion on how to quickly get an admin interface up and running for the single user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up going with this approach using AD authentication. I used the example in this post for inspiration:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/sql-server/13/10141669/using-excel-to-update-data-on-ms-sql-tables.aspx

Note that these functions live in different areas of the Excel Workbook (Objects, Modules, This Workbook), but here's a quick reference.

I also have each of the columns that are FK validating against the tables they reference.

Here are some code samples:

```
Public aCon As New ADODB.Connection
Public aCmd As New ADODB.Command

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  PopulateSheet
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub Connect()
  Dim sConn As String
  sConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Server=[SVR];Database=[DB]"
  With aCon
    .ConnectionString = sConn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
  End With
  BuildProcs
End Sub

Sub BuildProcs()
  With aCmd
    .ActiveConnection = aCon
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "[SPROC]"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@in_EmployeeID", adInteger, adParamInput)
  End With

End Sub

Sub PopulateSheet()
  Dim n As Integer, r As Long

  Dim aCmdFetchEmployees As New ADODB.Command
  Dim aRstEmployees As New ADODB.Recordset

  If aCon.State = adStateClosed Then Connect

  With aCmdFetchEmployees
    .ActiveConnection = aCon
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "[SPROC]"
    Set aRstEmployees = .Execute
  End With
  r = aRstEmployees.RecordCount

  Worksheets(1).Activate
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset aRstEmployees

  For n = 1 To aRstEmployees.Fields.Count
    Cells(1, n) = aRstEmployees(n - 1).Name
    Cells(1, n).EntireColumn.AutoFit
  Next
  Cells(1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim cell As Range
  If aCon.State = adStateClosed Then Connect
    With aCmd
      .Parameters(0) = Cells(Target.Row, 1)
      .Parameters(1) = Cells(Target.Row, 4)
      .Parameters(2) = Cells(Target.Row, 5)
      .Parameters(3) = Cells(Target.Row, 6)
      .Parameters(4) = Cells(Target.Row, 7)
      .Parameters(5) = Cells(Target.Row, 8)
      .Parameters(6) = Cells(Target.Row, 10)
      .Parameters(7) = Cells(Target.Row, 11)
      .Parameters(8) = Cells(Target.Row, 12)
      .Parameters(9) = Cells(Target.Row, 13)
      .Parameters(10) = Cells(Target.Row, 14)
      .Parameters(11) = Cells(Target.Row, 15)
      .Parameters(12) = Cells(Target.Row, 16)
      .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can start with this.

Create Macro Button on your excel file. Click New and then add this code.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim stSQL As String
Dim SNfound As String
    'Your sqlserver 2008 connection string
    Const stADO As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
    "" & _
    "Initial Catalog=YOurDB;" & _
    "Data Source=YourServer;UID=yourusername;PWD=yourpassword;"


     'SELECT FROM STORED PROCEDURE
     ' eg: select SN from SNTable where SN=@SN
         stSQL = "exec usp_SelectSN '" & "TESTSN" & "'"  
        Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
        With cnt
                  .CursorLocation = adUseClient
                  .Open stADO
                  .CommandTimeout = 0
        Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
        End With

                If rst.RecordCount = 0 Then
                      'NO SN FOUND ON YOUR DB
                Else

                      'RECORDS FOUND SHOW Retrieve SN from DB to message box
                    SNfound = rst.Fields("SN")

                    MsgBox ("Found:" & SNfound)

                End If

                Set rst = Nothing
                Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for that... I copied in your code and immediately got an error on the first line. I went to this approach (less robust) for loading the data.

Sub Load()
sqlstring = "  exec usp_GetEmployeeList"

connstring = _
"ODBC;DSN=[SVR];UID=;PWD=;Database=[DB]"

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("A1"), Sql:=sqlstring)
.Refresh
End With
End Sub

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to write back to the Update stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you create a simple Webpart that does the edit. You will have an easier time finding someone who can do C# to a database than vba. 
Coding a very rough webpart to any coding in this manner is pretty easy.

There are also plenty of coding samples for C# and webparts available.

You also have the benefit of keeping the code on the server without potentially exposing username/password combinations in clear text  within an office document.

This approach also enables you to smoothly improve the "quality" of the solution if it becomes more mission critical over time.

It does sound that you are following a scenario [covered nicely by this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769953.aspx)